# ant java compile throwing cannot find symbol

Tags: java, ant, compilation, classpath

I am working on a project that is having a layered Architecture.
I have a interface ABC and in that interface I have a enum XYZ

For ex

```
public interface ABC {
     public enum XYZ {
         CONSTANT1("SOMETHING"),
         CONSTANT2("SOMETHING3");
         final String name;

         private TYPE(String name) {
            this.name=name;
         }

         public String getName() {
            return this.name;
         }
     }
}
```

I am compiling this using ant and using this jar file in other layer. In that layer I am trying to access it like

```
String name=ABC.XYZ.CONSTANT1.getName();
```

I am getting symbol not found error during compile. I verified classpath is set properly.
I am using ant v 1.8 and java 1.6.

Why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't nest the enum in an interface. It's perfectly fine that it has its own source file named after the enum.

Second, I assume you mean `XYZ` instead of `TYPE` in your private constructor?

Last, you should be able to use it in that way, no matter if compiled via ant or within eclipse or directly using javac. Probably you have not compiled everything - the way you did it, there should be `ABC.class` (the interface), `ABC$XYZ.class` (the inner enum) and the class file of your calling class.

Comment: My requirement is like this only I have to nest enum inside an interface. 
Yeah I mean XYZ in my private constructor
I compiled using javac and ABC$XYZ.class is not present in my jar file

Comment: @spanhawk: Ok, then that's your answer. If you do `javac ABC.java`, this results in both files to be created - and the same should be done by javac ant task and both have to be copied to your jar file.